# Android - DropDownPreference not working in Landscape orientation

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I have a pretty weird issue. In my `SettingsActivity`, I have a DropDownPreference (the one that displays a list when clicked), and it works fine on Portrait mode.
However, when I go into Landscape mode, whenever the preference is clicked, it quickly disappears after being displayed, as if I had pressed the screen twice.

Here is my style, although I doubt there's something to do with it:

```
<style name="SettingsFragment">
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">?navBackground</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?colorPrim</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">?colorPrim</item>
        <item name="android:colorForeground">?textForeground</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?textForeground</item>
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogTheme</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">?accentVariant</item>
        <item name="preferenceCategoryTitleTextColor">?accentVariant</item>
</style>
```

Notes: My phone is a Samsung Galaxy Note 10, running Android 12 (API 31).

EDIT: Posting the activity's source code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ActivityUtils.applyTheme(this);
        getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.SettingsFragment, true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.settingsContainer, new SettingsFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings, rootKey);
        }
    }
}
```

PS: Parent theme does not change any attributes aside colors.

Comment: Sounds more like a lifecycle issue. Can you post the code for your activity?

Comment: @eimmer Posted.

Comment: @eimmer Also, the transition from portrait to landscape itself isn't the issue. Launching the whole app/activity already in landscape still produces the same problem.

Comment: try this : On the onConfigurationChanged() method call to spinner.invalidate();

Comment: @HamedGoharshad Hm... Which `spinner` exactly...?

Comment: replace spinner with your DropDown

Comment: @HamedGoharshad it didn't work :(